# cursor (caret) is not visible in contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

When I click on a text in a contenteditable div, the cursor does not appear to move.

once text is typed, the cursor becomes visible and text is entered in the clicked location.

its as if the cursor moves, but is not being redrawn.

I am unable to reproduce the bug in a simple jsfiddle environment.

Has anyone encountered such an issue before?

In the meantime I am trying to isolate the cause of the problem by removing css and javascript file references from the page. 
and reverse- starting with a blank page and adding js/css in attempt to reproduce.

EDIT IN RESPONSE TO COMMENTS BELOW:

Browser: chrome
Javascript modules: jquery, jquery ui, rangy.

I tried to remove all javascript. and the bug was still there.
It must be coming from the css. 
I am trying to single out the css rules involved. It appears to be a combination of things.
the :before psudo class (that I am using to show placeholder text in the div if it has no text) seems to be part of the problem.

Comment: Have you already tried simple hacks like... leave a nonbreaking space in the div, so it's not empty, then on the focus event remove/clear it?

Comment: What browser do you test in? And what javascript modules do you have loaded which could interfere? If you're not able to reproduce, we won't be either :-)

Comment: I've seen issues like this, primarily in Firefox. `contenteditable` is frustratingly buggy and even more frustratingly maintained.

Comment: The problem is reproduced when the div is not empty. so I dont think adding a non breaking space will help here. I also used javascript to set the cursor position. the cursor behaves in the same way as with a mouse click,. it does not appear to move, until a key is pressed- and the text appears in the expected location, along with the cursor. perhaps I need to simulate a keypress somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was traced to css3 3d transformations on a div that is located in the background of the contenteditable element.

Will try to place the background element in an iframe to resolve the issue.